# Turning off Group emails

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-groups

I joined many groups on LinkedIn, and I visit most of them daily.
The groups sends me a summary of their posts daily, I know there's an option to turn them off, but I can't find it. Can anyone help me in that?

Comment: See [this](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/web-development/TCH_WDD/769677-20311169) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found any easier way to do this.

- Hover your mouse pointer over your name at top right corner
- click on `settings`
- Login again
- Click on `Group, Companies and Applications tab`
- Click on `Set the frequency of group digest emails`
- Select the options for each of your group
- Click `Save Changes`

Thanks Alex for the help too.

Comment: It shouldn't be that difficult. It looks like they are violating CAN SPAM regulations that require clear unsubscribe links in the emails. I can't find how to unsubscribe even when visiting the site.